# Postman / Curl not working with Google App engine deployed app

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, postman, google-app-engine-python

I've got a Django app deployed on a Google App Engine (standard) which is working fine if I access it via the browser (any). However, I cannot run any tests using `curl` on the terminal or using the Postman app. When I try running curl, it times out:

```
curl --verbose -X GET "https://SERVER.appspot.com"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: https://SERVER.appspot.com/
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to SERVER.appspot.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Operation timed out after 300225 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300225 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The same app runs fine locally and I can run Postman / curl on it. If I try the same (i.e. curl or Postman) with a `http://` instead of `https://`, it works just fine (yet `https://` is working when using a browser).

What do I need to do to get it to work from the terminal?

Comment: Check the app logs https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: Logs are blank, as though these requests aren't making their way through

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a SSL 'trust' issue. One needs to add SSL support for each sub-domain mapped to an App Engine instance. Turns out, if you haven't done this correctly (in my case one of the CA intermediate certificates was missing from the .crt bundle), your browser may assume the site to be secure, but curl / postman will fail - or rather timeout without telling you much. I was able to run some tests on my sub-domain here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

It pointed out that the CA certificates supplied were incomplete and rated it B. Fixing this immediately fixed the curl and postman issues (and I assume postman internally is using curl ? I digress).